# Ajax и php функция возвращает пустую строку

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, строки

Не могу понять почему возвращает пустую строку а не  echo "success"

код JS

```
function submitForm(){
var category = $("#commentCategory").val();
 var nickname = $("#commentNickname").val();
    var message = $("#commentMessage").val();
  var email = $("#commentEmail").val();
var title = $("#commentTitle").val();


$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/commentprocess.php",
    data: "category=" + category + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&comment=" + message +"&email=" + email + "&title=" + title, //$(this).serialize(), 
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){  
          formSuccess(); 
            console.log('b');
            } else {
          formError();
          submitMSG(false,text);
                console.log(text);
                    }

    }
});
```

}

PHP

```
<?php
      $errorMSG = "";
        if(!empty($_POST['commentsubmit'])){
            $category = $_POST['commentCategory'];
            $nick = $_POST['commentNickname'];
            $commessage = $_POST['commentMessage'];
            $email = $_POST['commentEmail'];
            $title = $_POST['commentTitle'];

             if ($title == '' OR $nick == '' OR $email == '' OR $category == '' OR $commessage == '')
             {

                  $errorMSG = "Заполните поля";
                 exit();
             }
             else 
             {
                 $user=R::dispense( 'comments' );
                  $user->category = $category;
                  $user->nickname = $nick;
                  $user->comment = $commessage;
                  $user->email = $email;
                  $user->title = $title;
                  R::store($user);

                 if ($errorMSG == "") {
                     echo "success";
                 }
             }

        }

        ?>
```

подключение осуществляется RedBeanom. Новичек в этой теме.

пример поля form

```
 <form role="form" id="commentForm" data-toggle="validator" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label for="commentTitle" class="h4">Тема</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="commentTitle" placeholder="Тема" required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

> почему возвращает пустую строку а не echo "success"

Из-за этого условия:

```
if(!empty($_POST['commentsubmit'])){
  ...
```

В данных, которые Вы передаете на сервер, нет элемента с ключом `'commentsubmit'`.

*(Очевидно, это `name` кнопки с `type="submit"`, которая раньше (дo `ajax`-a) отвечала за отправку формы.)*

Вы можете его добавить:

```
data: "commentsubmit=true&category=" + category + "&nickname=" + nickname + "&comment=" + message +"&email=" + email + "&title=" + title,
```

Или убрать условие в php.